# IFrame scrolling attribute set from onload event working differently on IE11 and edge/chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe

I am setting attribute "scrolling" from onload event and it is working differently in IE11 and Edge

```
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myFrame").scrolling = "no";  
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
</body>
```

This stops scrolling in Edge but not in IE11, when I open this on edge of IE emulation mode, there also scrolling is happening. Strangely other attributes like height and width work fine in both edge and IE11.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: hi @XudongPeng, sorry I just checked the answer, I changed my code to use scrolling inline. But I had one question, upon further investigation I got to know that scrolling attribute in IE11 is not working only if we set it dynamically, but working if we set it inline. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the attribute `scrolling` is aleady deprecated, if you have to use this attribute in iframe, you can add it in html code manually instead of adding it dynamically through javascript.

Something like this:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://example.com/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

In addition, IE will end support soon. So I recommend that you focus more on modern browsers such as Microsoft Edge, Chrome instead of IE.